# How to get the output of ssh when the command has a command to change user

Tags: shell, ssh

When I use ssh to run command on a remote machine, I will get the output from shell. However, if I add

```
sudo su - user2
```

I will get no output. Now, I cannot do

```
ssh user2@host
```

Because of some permission issue.

Is there any way to get the output for the following command?

```
ssh user1@host 'sudo su - user2; wc -l tmp.txt'
```

Thanks to @laenkeio. Using sudo -u user2 can run some simple programs.

However, when I need to call a python script which needs some enviroment variable for user2, the script was not able to find those default path by using `sudo -u user2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the appropriate sudo rights on `host` you should be able to do it with:

```
ssh -t user1@host 'sudo -u user2 wc -l tmp.txt'
```

Using `sudo -u` means "execute as user2", thus avoiding the extra `su -`. And `-t` forces ssh to allocate a tty so that `sudo` can ask for your password.

Comment: command sudo -u user2 seems not be able to load all enviroment variables for user2. If my script need to fetch some enviroment variable, it seems to fail.

Comment: If you need to emulate a login as user2 you need to add `-i`, ie. `sudo -iu user2 wc -l tmp.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot do `ssh user2@host` for some permission issue, you'll not be able to run `ssh user1@host 'sudo su - user2; ...` for the same reason...
And, even with no permission issue, when doing `su - user` you'll be requested for a password...

Comment: The cluster admin regularly replace .ssh/authorized_keys file with the default one and this account doesn't have a password.

Comment: By default, you can **not** `su - user` if the user does not have a password... See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115090/32839 ...

Comment: I can do `sudo su - user` without a password, but not `su - user`.

Comment: Ok... But why doing `sudo su` when you can do `sudo -s` ? (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218201/32839)

Comment: I also need to load user2's environment variable. `sudo -s` seems to have some problem.